# Why does the CSS height property not get calculated properly for a div with display:table containing a div with display:caption?

Tags: css

I can't figure out why the height of the #container div is calculated correctly at 200px when a display:table-row is applied to the #header div and it's too large when a display:table-caption is applied to the #header div.

I've tested this in Chrome 35

Does someone know why this is the case and/or is there a simple fix? 
( preferably without javascript or adding extra divs)?

I want the #header div's height to be as small as it's content, and it's width to be 100% of the #container div, and the #container to fit exactly in the #main div.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2SKY4/

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:#ff0; 
}
#container {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 90%;
    display:table;
    height:100%;
}
#header {
    background-color:#F0F;
    display:table-caption;
}
#splitpanel {
    display:table-row;
    background-color:#0ff;
}
#leftpanel {
    background-color: #f00;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: table-cell;
}
#rightpanel {
    background: #00f;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">Header</div>
        <div id="splitpanel">
            <div id="leftpanel"></div>
            <div id="rightpanel"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want. the fiddle already has like you want it seems. 
you are better off showing snapshots and say what you want. you are using "display" of different types which also doesnt make much sense. can you please describe what structure you want in snapshot?

Comment: The two columns are of the 'table' have their lower scrollbars protruding from the #main div. I want those columns completely inside the yellow reactangle.

Comment: If you change the display attribute of the #header to table-row it does that correctly, but then the header takes too much vertical space. This is a minimal repro of a bug i've been asked to fix and at my job. I'd like the solution to be very minimal, and without javascript because this is on a page that has been extended and grown and made to do some unholy wizardry already. Id like to make it simpler, not more complex. ;-)

Comment: your structure is incorrect is the reason why it is creating problem. i dont know significance of all the css styles you have aapplied and lots of them seem useless. you can create a structure you want without using such css styles when you dont understand what they do.

Comment: Now, its not working because your header takes up some width and your splitpanel is trying to take 100% width. since header is caption, it is not taken as an element that takes up the share of table's total height and splitpanel tries to take 100%(200px) which makes it overflow.
consider this as a browser common behaviour and modify your structure according to your need.